# What is the difference between non-local optical response and local optical response?

Tags: optics, solid-state-physics, nanoscience, non-locality, photonics

Does anyone knows what is the difference between non-local optical response and local optical response in metal-dielectric-metal?

Comment: Can you add a little bit more context? Are you talking about a metal insulator metal waveguide?

Comment: in Nanostructures layers, for example first layer is dielectric and second is metal and again dielectric.